# Is that possible to answer to page rating using Facebook Graph API v2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I'm going to have the app for my page that use `Facebook Graph API` and automatically sends `Thank You` answer to everyone who put good rating. Is that possible through Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. There are a couple of things that restrict you from doing this.

1. A Page cannot initiate a conversation with a user. This is true for both the API and the main Facebook Site, which means that you will not be able to send the user a direct message.
2. The 'Ratings' edge of the page object is a Read Only edge. This means that you cannot publish to this edge or comment on any of the ratings returned.

Ratings documentation can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

Comment: That's pretty bad. And #1 is not correct. Page _can_ answer to Ratings of its own. Try yourself.

Comment: In #1 I am referring to messaging as you said "sends Thank You answer to everyone"